# R geom_forecast object not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecast

I want to create a forecasting plot via `ggplot2`. So, I have been trying to follow this [example](https://rdrr.io/cran/forecast/man/geom_forecast.html), however the desired output is not as intended, as I would like to have `year` on `x-axis` and `AvgTMean` on the y-axis`.

Purpose is the forecast the next `10` years.

How can I do this?

Data (`AvgTMaxYear`):

```
structure(list(year = 1980:2021, AvgTMean = c(24.2700686838937, 
23.8852956598276, 25.094446596092, 24.1561175050287, 24.157183605977, 
24.3047482638362, 24.7899738481466, 24.5756232655603, 24.5833086228592, 
24.7344695534483, 25.3094451071121, 25.2100615173707, 24.3651692293534, 
24.5423890611494, 25.2492166633908, 24.7005097837931, 24.2491591827443, 
25.0912281781322, 25.0779264303305, 24.403294248319, 24.4983991453592, 
24.4292324356466, 24.8179824927011, 24.7243948463075, 24.5086534543966, 
24.2818632071983, 24.4567195220259, 24.8402224356034, 24.6574465515086, 
24.5440715673563, 23.482670620977, 24.9979594684914, 24.5452453980747, 
24.9271462811494, 24.7443215819253, 25.8929839790805, 25.1801908261063, 
25.2079308058908, 25.0722425561207, 25.4554644289799, 25.4548979078736, 
25.0756772250287)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

Method 1:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)

# Convert to timeseries object
AvgTMaxYearTS = ts(AvgTMaxYear)

# Plot
autoplot(AvgTMaxYearTS) + geom_forecast()
```

Output:

[image]

Method 2:

```
# Using fortify.ts
p = ggplot(aes(x = year, y = AvgTMean), data = AvgTMaxYear)
p = p + geom_line()
p + geom_forecast()
```

Error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'AvgTMean' not found
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match the error message you included. Which one is *actually* coming up as not found? Either way, I can't reproduce the error, I get the plot that I assume you're expecting

Comment: @camille, error is associated with the 2nd method.

Comment: I'm running your code without an error, and the error message in your title isn't the same as the error message you show in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your second method it runs like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
p = ggplot(aes(x = year, y = AvgTMean), data = AvgTMaxYear)
p = p + geom_line()
p + geom_forecast()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Cheer, I don't why I got the `object not found error` maybe I should restart `RStudio` and run it again. What is the `middle blue flat line` in confidence intervals?

Comment: @Mandalorian, The blue line is your forecast where the prediction intervals of 80% and 95% are shown as blue areas. Here some extra info: [Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-better-interactive-forecast-plots-using-r-and-dygraph-29bdd7146066)

Comment: Thank you, one last question, why is the blue forecast line `flat`? I was expecting wiggles similar to the past data. Should I post this as a new question?